# Anylogic Queueing Priority based

Tags: comparison, product, priority-queue, anylogic, thread-priority

so the initial problem is that I have 2 products, one individual and one standard. After the separate products got produced, they will send out, but in the logistics department, there is only 1 worker. So how do I prioritize the individual product? The worker should always send out the individual good before the standard product. 
I'm stuck because I have no idea how to queue, either agent comparison or priority-based, but how does the block knows which product is which?
Thx

Comment: The question is not clear enough: what you tried to achieve? example input & output?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach:

1. add a parameter "myPriority" to your product agent type (integer)
2. when creating a individualized one, set it to 10. Else to 1
3. in your queue, set it up as below. This will ensure the queue always moves higher-prio agents to the front. Make sure your queue block expects agents of your Product type
   [image]

Also check example models and the help :)